# Erro no Cosmos DB: Request rate is large

Tags: mongodb, cosmos-db

Estou fazendo um filtro para pegar o ultimo registro enviado para uma `collection` por um dispositivo e a consulta é bem simples:

```
db.getCollection('Device').find({'ID':'1234'}).sort({DateTime: -1}).limit(1)
```

porém, se eu fizer com `limit(1)` ele dá erro o seguinte erro:

> "Request rate is large".

mas, se fizer com `limit` **2** ou **3** ou **10** ou **n** funciona.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Li algumas coisas de escolher o servidor cosmos na região mais proxima do servidor devido ao desempenho mas nada concreto do problema em si além da mensagem. Uma alternativa, mesmo que "imprópria", seria tratar o resuiltado com limit 2

Comment: Sim... eu to fazendo com limit 2 e na camada de serviço (um nodejs) eu retorno somente o primeiro item. 
Está assim em produção hoje.

Vou pesquisar sobre a região, obrigado pela ajuda :)